# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) in Android

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I'm working on a project that needs to convert images to GIF. 
I'm using this opensource( using JNI) but I have a problem with some devices (such as google galaxy nexus, nexus 7). 
The source link here : http://www.mediafire.com/?mvn31u3ht8nod39

Thanks for your attention.